# Artifactory backup

Tags: artifactory, derby

I would like to do a backup artifactory. My artifactory is started by docker in VM. Arti version 6.12 in default configurations.

```
<config version="1">
    <chain template="file-system"/>
</config>
```

The metadata is stored in a Derby database (by default). All files are mounted in the volume /art/data (docker ... -v /art/data/arti.docker.home:/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory) 
Artifact and database are about 1TB 
I don't want to use build-in backup mechanism from the UI. I'm going to make backup /art/data. Is it a proper aproche?

Answer (score 0):

Anything that would allow you a swift restore is a valid approach.

I advise you to test a restore scenario from the backup you plan to take. If you are able to restore successfully - you can implement this solution.